Can not run the old flutter project with exoplayer
I have a problem with my project that I have been fixing for 2 days and still continue.
I'm using flutter version: 1.20.4. Everything was okay the last time I ran it (29-08-2024), but now it's failed on building. Could anyone have a solution for this, Thank you for reading
Error Detail:

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':video_player:compileReleaseAidl'.


Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':video_player:releaseCompileClasspath'.
Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.6.
Required by:
project :video_player
Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.9.6.
Required by:
project :video_player
Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.9.6.
Required by:
project :video_player
Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.9.6.
Required by:
project :video_player


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


